# Return full directory using pattern

Tags: linux, matlab, path

My question is simple, yet I did not found any easy solution to it.
Lets say I have a main directory with N files or folders inside, and I also have a Pattern (just a partial name) of the file/folder which I want to return the full directory. How can I do this in a simple way? I will give an example below:

```
main_dir='/home/ddd/main_folder/';

files_in_main_dir=ls(main_dir)

pattern='*Ginger*';

%%% code to return the full path 

%  ?

%%%

files_in_main_dir=

Cupcake

Donut

Gingerbread


return_path=

/home/ddd/main_folder/Gingerbread
```

Edit:
This is a possible solution, yet horrible:

```
files_in_main_dir=ls(main_dir);
find_ls=strfind(files_in_main_dir,' ');
find_pattern=strfind(files_in_main_dir,pattern);

begin_pattern=find_ls(find(find_ls<find_pattern,1,'last'));

if length(find_ls)>find(find_ls<find_pattern,1,'last'), ...
        end_pattern=find_ls(find(find_ls<find_pattern,1,'last')+1); 
else 
        end_pattern=length(files_in_main_dir);
end

pattern=files_in_main_dir(begin_pattern+1:end_pattern-1);

full_dir_pattern=[main_dir,pattern]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but it seems like you would not want to do this with string matching.

Here is what I would do:

```
d = dir(fullfile(main_dir,'*ginger*'))
```

Now you can get the full filenames like so:

```
fullfile(main_dir,d(1).name)
```

Comment: Both suggestions work for my problem. This is however even simpler. Weirdly I thought that the dir function did not worked with wildcards. Also I thought that the behaviour was the same as the ls function which returns not Gingerbread but if Gingerbread is a folder returns what is inside. Thanks